# How to set local web storage directory in JxBrowser

Tags: jxbrowser

We are using JxBrowser and are pretty happy with it.

What we could not figure out by now was how to set the directory which is used as local web storage. 
What do we have to do to set this directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the Browser instance with the specific BrowserContext instance passed as a parameter. The BrowserContext should be created with the Chromium data directory specified:

```
Browser browser = new Browser(new BrowserContext(new BrowserContextParams(fullCustomFolderPath)));
```

In this case the local web storage folder will be located by following path: "fullCustomFolderPath\Local Storage"